# Split table according to string in a column

Tags: r, string

This should be an easy one, but I found no solution which worked and was at the same time elegant...

I have a table which has in one column a string. Some strings start with letter "E" and others start with letter "B". How do I generate two tables where the first one contains only the rows with strings starting with "E" and the second one rows where strings start with "B"?

EDIT:

Example:

```
Col1 Col2 StringCol Col4
1    1    Bacteria  3.2
2    3    Eukaryote 1.0
4    1    Bacteria  1.5
0    2    Bacteria  1.2
2    0    Eukaryote 0.9
```

Now the data frame should be split into two frames, one with all the rows "Bacteria" and the other with all the rows "Eukaryote".

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `grepl` for string matching. Thus, one option would

```
# Some sampledata:
yourdata <- data.frame(id=1:5, stringcol=c("bus", "easter", "Bunny", "nothing", "End"))

subset(yourdata, grepl("^B", stringcol)) 
# ^ marks the beginning of a string, then followed by "B"

# For E:
subset(yourdata, grepl("^E", stringcol))
```

If you want the matching to be case insensitive, you could do

```
subset(yourdata, grepl("^[Bb]", stringcol))
```

A totally different approach would be to use

```
subset(yourdata, substring(stringcol, 1, 1) == 'B') 
# substring(..., 1, 1) extracts just the first letter from your string.
```

### Edit:

If you know the whole string, you could always do the most elegant version:

```
subset(yourdata, stringcol == 'Bacteria')
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not remember about "subset". Elegant and easy solution. Exactly that I was looking for! :-)

Comment: OK, the Edited version is even easier. But I do have some stuff after "Bacteria" and "Eukaryote" which is random. But thanks anyway!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#reproducible data
df <- read.table(text="Col1 Col2 StringCol Col4
1    1    Bacteria  3.2
2    3    Eukaryote 1.0
4    1    Bacteria  1.5
0    2    Bacteria  1.2
2    0    Eukaryote 0.9", header=TRUE)

#subset
df_B <- df[ substr(df$StringCol,1,1)=="B", ]
df_E <- df[ substr(df$StringCol,1,1)=="E", ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is found in the title of your question: `split`

```
split(mydf, grepl("^Eu", mydf$StringCol))
# $`FALSE`
#   Col1 Col2 StringCol Col4
# 1    1    1  Bacteria  3.2
# 3    4    1  Bacteria  1.5
# 4    0    2  Bacteria  1.2
# 
# $`TRUE`
#   Col1 Col2 StringCol Col4
# 2    2    3 Eukaryote  1.0
# 5    2    0 Eukaryote  0.9
```